# Automatically create journey of a Salesforce contact record in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can we create a journey of a contact present in SAlesforce on the mArketing cloud journey builder whenever a contact is created or an existing contact is updated whose journey is not present in Marketing cloud.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'create a journey of a contact'? Do you mean that you want to inject new/updated contacts from Salesforce into an running Journey Builder Interaction? Also, when you say 'whose journey is not present' do you mean that the Contact is already not moving through a Journey Builder Interaction? (For example, if a Contact is updated in Salesforce, then enters an Interaction, if that record is updated again, then you don't want them to re-enter the Interaction). Please confirm as your question is currently too ambiguous.

Comment: yes , I want to inject the new/updated contacts from Salesforce into a :- 
a)running journey
b)different journey(create a new journey automatically)
and for "whose journey is not present" , yes I mean that the contact is not moving through a journey Builder interaction.(and you got it correct that if a contact is created enroll it for a journey and if the same contact is updated then it is not enrolled for a new journey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to create an Event in a Journey Builder Interaction and select a Salesforce Data Event as the Event Type, then follow the steps to [configure the Salesforce Event](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/). Using this Event type, you can fire the event when a record is created or updated in your chosen Salesforce Object.

Once you create a Salesforce Data Event, Marketing Cloud will:

1. Automatically create an Attribute Set in a 'Sales and Service Cloud' Attribute Group
2. Automatically create Channel Address Order entries in Contacts Configuration
3. Create an Event Source Data Extension
4. Create a Flow in Sales Cloud

On the whole it works really well and Contacts are injected into the Interaction within seconds of being created or updated in the Salesforce object.

Regarding your requirement to 'create a new journey automatically', you can't do this through the interface. You can programmatically create and publish Interactions using the Interactions methods in the [REST API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html) but I'm curious to learn what is your use case for wanting to do this?

To answer your final point, you can determine whether the Contact should enter an Interaction by determining the Contact Entry mode in the [Interaction Settings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/). You can choose whether:

1. The Contact can only ever enter the Interaction once.
2. The Contact can enter the Interaction at any time (so the same Contact can exist multiple times in an Interaction).
3. the Contact can only enter the Interaction if they have previously exited it.

Comment: thanks for the reply . And also , is it possible to 'create a new journey automatically' without using API

Comment: Hi @JiteshGoel, no it's not possible to create a new journey automatically. I'm keen to learn of a use case why you would want to do this.